# Scorched plug and socket

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, cord-and-plug

My dishwasher stopped working.  I pulled it out and discovered a scorched plug with some carbon damage to the socket. Do you think this is a dishwasher fault? The socket still works...

I want to know if it is worth going back to the shop I bought the dishwasher from -- it's only two months out of guarantee.  Clearly, it's a worry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, a poor connection in the plug has caused it to overheat.  The 13A fuse gets warm in normal use.  But if there is a bad connection, it can get really hot.

The faulty plug has then damaged the socket.  Both should be replaced.

It doesn't indicate a fault in the dishwasher itself.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a *series arc fault*  due to poor contact between fuse and fuse holder.  This is why the US is requiring arc fault interruptors on some circuits.  The socket is probably blameless, but it took a critical hit so it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the outlet,socket,still works, then the problem is the dishwasher. You could try plugging the washer into another socket to be sure. Either way, since the socket was burned, it should be replaced since it's been heated up and burnt more than it was designed to be. I've seen many molded plugs fail just like that one did. Based on your added photo of the plug, it looks like a bad fuse connection in the plug. The store you bought it from might honor the warranty. If not, try ordering a new plug and cord from the manufacturer or get one from an appliance store.